# shorten if else, possible?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
 if(count($a) > 0){
   $a = $b;
 } else { 
   $c = $b;
 }
```

Is it possible to re-write this, using ternary operators? or any way to shorten it? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(count($a) > 0) ? $a = $b : $c = $b;
```

Comment: +1, but, while technically valid, I'd feel dirty doing this in production code. Seems like a good way to confuse somebody.

Comment: He asks if it is possible to shorten. You can't get it any shorter than this.

Comment: Sidenote: parentheses around condition are not necessary

Comment: @ponciste Yes. assignment (as well as any valid expression) is allowed as ternary operand

Comment: write it like $a=count($a)>0?$b:$c; now use it here and there in a 10000+ loc project and then hire a new developer to change something, enjoy.

Comment: @Adarsh That's because `count()` always return `1` when its parameter is not an array (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: @hindmost, kawashita86: Ooops... How could I miss that... Count deals with arrays... My mistake...

Comment: @Daan thanks! can you tell me why I can't replace $c = $b with echo "ok"? I get an syntax error

Comment: @user1192403 `echo (count($a) > 0) ? $a = $b : "Ok";` write it like this. The echo is not needed.

Comment: @hindmost i only saw your comment now, i tried it by myself and figured out it is allowed. I don't know why I thought it wasn't possible, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @user1192403 Because ternary operand should be an expression, i.e. something that have value. it may be a function returning value, e.g. `print`. but `echo` doesn't return value, so it cannot be ternary operand

Comment: @Daan `echo (count($a) > 0) ? $a = $b : "Ok";`. This code doesn't work properly since it outputs value of `$b` if condition is `true`. I think this is not desired behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use ternary operators

```
cond ? true : false
```

You can see the full documentation here

http://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 0):

try-

```
<?php
$a=array(1,23,3,4,5);
echo (count($a) > 0)  ? "true":  "false";
?>

OUTPUT-true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
count ($a) > 0 AND $a = $b OR $c = $b;
```

Comment: can you tell me why when I replace $c = $b with echo "ok", i get an syntax error? I can only assign variables, not call methods within ternary operators? Thanks!

Comment: In this case you could only use functions but not control structures etc. use print() instead.

Comment: `echo` goes in front like `echo count ($a) > 0 AND 'true' OR 'false';`

Comment: you could make any structure: (count ($a) > 0 AND print ($a = MyFunction())) OR ($b = DoSomethingElse() XOR exit()); # In this case XORed function will be executed even if $b is FALSE